# How can I make the width of the select dropdown box change based on the width required for the option? Just CSS preferred

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, css-selectors, html-select

I am making a copy of the Amazon home page, and noticed that in their search bar, the category search drop down menu is whatever width the option is. For example, when you select "Technology", the box is wider than when "Men" is selected. I want to copy this functionality. I've tried inline block, width fit-content, max-width min-width things, all to no success, probably due to misunderstanding of how the select tag is styled. The text either gets clipped off or the width becomes the width of the widest possible option and stays that width for every option, I want the width to be dynamic.

```css
@font-face {
    src: url(./AmazonEmber_Rg.ttf);
    font-family: amazon;
}


* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: amazon;
}


#navflex-top {
    display: flex;
    height: 3.5rem;
    background-color: #131921;
}


.navflex-item {
    margin: 0px;
    
}


.hover-box:hover {
    border: 1px solid white;
}

#navflex-item-1 {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 15vw;
    min-width: 8rem;
}

#amazon-logo {
    background-image: url(./amazon_logo.png);
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 70%;
    width: 70%;
    margin-top: 1rem;
}

#navflex-item-2 {
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: cen;
    width: 20vw;
    min-width: 10rem;
}

#navflex-2-left-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

#navflex-2-pin {
    display: flex;
    width: 1rem;
    height: 1rem;
    background-image: url(./map_pin.png);
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#navflex-2-right-container {
    margin-left: 0.2rem;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}

#navflex-2-hello {
    font-size: 0.8rem;
}

#navflex-2-location {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 0.9rem;
}

#navflex-item-3 { 
    width: 80%;
    display: flex;
    margin: 0.3rem 0.1rem;
    
    
}

#search-dropdown {
    color: black;
    font-size: 0.7rem;
    border-radius: 0.3rem;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.search-dropdown-content {
    white-space: nowrap; 
    padding: 0;
}


#search-bar {
    width: 80%;
    flex-grow: 1
}

#search-icon {
    width: 2rem;
}


#navflex-item-4 {
    width: 10%;
}
#navflex-item-5 {
    width: 10%;
}
#navflex-item-6 {
    width: 10%;
}
#navflex-item-7 {
    width: 10%;
}
#navflex-item-8 {
    width: 10%;
}
#navflex-item-9 {
    width: 10%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Amazon Copy</title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar">
        <div id="navflex-top">
            <div class="navflex-item hover-box" id="navflex-item-1">
                <div id="amazon-logo"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="navflex-item hover-box" id="navflex-item-2">
                <div id="navflex-2-left-container">
                    <div id="navflex-2-pin"></div>
                </div>
                <div id="navflex-2-right-container">
                    <div id="navflex-2-hello">Hello</div>
                    <div id="navflex-2-location">Select your address</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="navflex-item" id="navflex-item-3">
                    <select class="search-flex-item" id="search-dropdown">
                        <option value="none" selected disabled hidden>All</option>
                        <option class="search-dropdown-content">All Departments</option>
                        <option class="search-dropdown-content">Appliances</option>
                        <option class="search-dropdown-content">Apps and Games</option>
                        <option class="search-dropdown-content">Men</option>
                        <option class="search-dropdown-content">Women</option>
                        <option class="search-dropdown-content">Technology</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type="text" class="search-flex-item" id="search-bar"></input>
                    <div class="search-flex-item" id="search-icon"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="navflex-item" id="navflex-item-4"></div>
            <div class="navflex-item" id="navflex-item-5"></div>
            <div class="navflex-item" id="navflex-item-6"></div>
            <div class="navflex-item" id="navflex-item-7"></div>


        </div>
        <div id="navflex-bottom">

        </div>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey! Have you tried looking at the devtools on Amazon's site? Also, please format your code as a functioning snippet :)

Comment: Thanks, illl setup the snippet right now! Yes I have been comparing but their code is very convoluted and even the styles I did compare didn't seem anything that would make theirs work and mine not

Comment: @Ford I also wanted to customize a drop down but drop downs have limited customizability i suggest you to make a custom drop down or checkout a boostrap one

Comment: While it looks like amazon does use a HTML select element, I would have to agree with Mad max that it's probably vastly easier to use a library or something that does it for you, or to write a custom CSS solution yourself. [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bB14uo0Tu5A) and others like it might help